# How to mount two king-sized bed heads horizontally to a wall to use as an open closet/shelving?

Tags: wood, shelving, closet

I have [two king-sized bed heads](https://www.bensonsforbeds.co.uk/hip-hop-ottoman-bed-frame/) leftover from failed customer service experience. I've tried to give them away on Freecycle, to no avail. It seems like a waste (and hassle where I live in London) to throw them away as the wood is sturdy and matches my bed.

So, instead of building a standard built-in wardrobe, I had the idea to attach these horizontally to the wall (one above head-height, the other around knee height) to provide shelving. I would then later attach curtains to it.

My question: **how would I go about securing these to the wall (if at all?) so that I could achieve my goal above?**

Here is a crude diagram I drew while procrastinating sleep when I had the idea... The yellow part is the bed head horizontally coming out from the rear wall. The other headboard would be attached similarly, but nearer to ground level, aligning to the left-hand end of the wall, so that they would overlap a little in the middle.

[image: crude free-hand drawing of my bed head 'wardrobe']

Specifications of the bed heads:

- 10-15kg
- 99cm standing height or depth from the wall when horizontal [may take some off the bottom to make this not so deep]
- 160cm width

Other details:

- Intended heights from the ground: ~180cm for upper one, 50cm for lower one [not pictured]
- Drywall is ~40mm thick on the outside wall (right in drawing), ~20mm thick in long wall of drawing
- Construction of apartment is metal stud

Comment: Some angle brackets along the wall would support the weight. Are the headboards themselves solid enough to hold a load in the center area. Many headboards are strong on the edges and more decorative in the middle. If they are strong enough I might support the edge away from the wall from the ceiling with strut or chain in a couple of locations to match the curtain plan.

Comment: @EdBeal They are yeah; pretty solid all around. The chain idea sounds great, actually. I guess with a toggle bolt hook mounted through the ceiling drywall on the corners/edges away from the wall. Great idea!

Comment: You definitely should fix the "free" edge thoroughly in order to avoid any leverage effects. You don't want to be there if a board (especially the upper one) comes down because your mounting material on the walls experiences forces of unexpected strength and directions. Btw. why not mount legs so the boards can stand on the floor? Then the wall-mounting only needs to keep the construction in place without absorbing that much force.

Comment: If you do ceiling mount I would try to hit a rafter , there will be two much weight for a toggle bolt unless it is a steel lath type of construction.

Comment: @puck I did consider this but wasn't sure if it would be as 'aesthetically pleasing' :) Any thoughts on what would make good legs for such a construction? I don't have access to tools for metal working, otherwise some simple, small, metal legs might work. I've considered asking a local furniture maker whether he'd be able to do something. I may still do so.

Comment: @Ashley Wooden legs should be ok too, no need to use metal. There could be ready-to-use wood/metal legs in different lengths at least for the lower board. Look around in your diy-store, ask stuff - but with care as some of them don't know things reliably. The upper board is some more challenge with legs. If you are good you can attach the open edge to the ceiling? Oh and make it safe. If it is not really above everyone's head, take care nobody will run into it or bump their head when bending down under the board and then raising up! "I've considered asking a local furniture maker" - good idea.